# how to create dynamic link in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I would like to create a "Live Preview" button for themes in Shopify. Think about each theme as a product in Shopify and each theme product page has a "Live Preview" button that goes to live demo page of theme.

I would like to list all of my themes to my Shopify website with CSV and this CSV includes "Live Preview" link of the theme.

I want this "preview link" button grabs this link for theme product page.

I wrote this code "product-template.liquid" assign it to 
But, it does not work

{% assign preview_link = product.description | split: "Product Description" | first%}
.
.
.

Live Preview

I need the code grab Live Preview button from

Comment: Are all the themes installed on the same demo store? If so, then you can just use a link to [current page]?preview_theme_id=[theme id]

Comment: I would like to create a similar website just like www.themeforest.net . In this webstite, each theme has a demo link which goes to demo website of the website theme. I would like to create same "demo link" with uploading theme with CSV file

Comment: You are aware that you have a limit on how many themes you can upload in Shopify (15-20 I don't remember the exact limit).  So if your idea is to have a full blown  theme forest in Shopify you can't.

Comment: That s not what I need. I am trying to create a custom product page on Shopify. In my custom product page, there will be a button named "Live Preview" which will open in a new window and it will be different for each product. I will list all of my products with CSV file and this link will be included in the CSV so Shopify will grab this link for each product and assign it this button. I am trying to figure our how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access other themes preview url, you have to put them in your CSV file manually and only then upload it